# How would you construct this php - mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a turn based game, and trying to construct the matching function, when a player chooses to play with a random opponent. I'm a noob when it comes to mysql so I need some help.

I was thinking about doing this:

1. When a player chooses to play against a random opponent, check the "waiting_list" table to see if there's any opponents there.
2. If there isn't any opponent, add the player to the waiting list.
3. It there is an opponent on the waiting list, remove the player from the list, and start the game with the other player.

My concern is, if I do it like this, is there any chance the same player on the waiting list, will be choosen by several players. Imagine if there is 100,000 player choosing the auto match feature, will the database (phpmyadmin) be able to handle it fine? How would you construct the logic?

Thanks

Comment: you can assign the players in the same order they entered the waiting list using a timestamp column (considering that there is a auto matching feature and not a choice).. also, just an observation: phpmyadmin is just a tool used to manage databases, not a driver; I think you are using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help prevent a single player from getting pulled into multiple games, you could do the waiting list with an additional column (if not there already) for the "GameIDAssigned", defaulting to 0 (or even PlayAgainstPerson ).

At the time of querying the data available for and displayed to many players, the records may all have similar timestamps, but you only want 1.  So, pick one at some random method, then assign the ID where it equals the timestamp and no game assigned.  If it comes back that 1 record was updated, its yours.  If it was assigned to someone else, the GameIDAssigned will have been filled in, thus preventing you from getting it assigned a second time.   Such as...

```
PersonIDFromWaitingList = SomeValueEvenIfBySQLSubSelect

Update YourWaitingListTable
   set GameIDAssigned = SomeCurrentGameIDSequence
   where DateTimeStampColumn = ValueWhenOriginallyQueried
     AND GameIDAssigned = 0
```

Without seeing any other elements of how your game is structured, or columns of tables, not much more I can offer at this time, but hopefully enough for you to get the idea.  If one waiting list person is ATTEMPTED to be assigned by multiple people at the same time, only the first one who gets the updated done (while the gameIDAssigned still = 0) wins and everyone else trying to get that person will miss and need to try the next available...

Comment: AFAIK depending on the MySQL storage engine, this is not safe.

Comment: Multiple revisions of the same row. A concurrent read can get the previous one.

Comment: @hakre, ok, that makes sense, I'll add that to the back of my mind for any future such impact...

Answer (score 3):

> My concern is, if I do it like this, is there any chance the same player on the waiting list, will be choosen by several players.

What you describe with your points 1.) to 3.) is a so called Business Transaction, you have an *atomic* operation here that can be performed by one player at once only.

You should encapsulate the operation therefore into an object that deals with it, so you have an interface in your business logic to perform that transaction.

Then you need to implement the transaction. A transaction can be successful or it fails, you can handle failures with return values or exceptions.

The transaction itself must ensure that your concern is removed. That could be done in MySQL by locking the match table exclusively, do the match, remove or add the player/oponent to the waiting list and release the lock.

See [12.3.5. `LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES` Syntax<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html).

Table locks have performance implications because as long a table is locked, no other session can access it (waiting until the lock is released).

It's therefore wise to keep the time of the lock short. If the transaction takes 10 milliseconds you can multiply it with the number of concurrent active transactions to get your performance expressed in time:

```
0.010 seconds * 100 000 transactions = ~ 16.7 minutes
```

Note that it's not likely you have 100 000 concurrent transactions because not all players match at once. However you need to keep track of the numbers, because your system might stall after some time.